# knockoutjs bind part of string

Tags: knockout.js, javascript-databinding

I have a string in my web page with the current format:
"This are the games which USERNAME subscribed".
USERNAME takes the logged in username value.
I only want to bind  the USERNAME attribute, and mantain the rest of the string in the same html element, rather than having a span with the first part, a different one with the binding attribute, and a last one with the last part.

I haven't something like this anywhere.
Does anyone knows how to do this, or if this is even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do it that way:

```
<span data-bind="text: 'This are the games which '  + USERNAME() + ' subscribed'" ></span>
```

although not very nice when you want to localize your application...